# Can a listview be formatted as a dropdown selector via JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I would like to format a list view as a dropdown. Is this possible?
Power Apps seems not to be an option due lack of taxonomy fields integration.

Comment: Where you want to create a dropdown? In list view or in list form? You can to create a dropdown for only one field in list view?

Comment: in the listview. showing all items options. (based on one column value, ofc.)

Comment: can you add some examples to your question what exactly are you trying to do? If you can add any screenshots/images that will also help to understand your requirements.

Comment: it's pretty straightforward actually. I want to have dynamic filtering between list/libraries webparts and the dynamic filtering source to be displayed as filter/dropdown instead the whole list items view.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using JSON formatting. In JSON formatting, you cannot read values from other rows/items. Also, JSON code repeats for each list item/row.

Comment: thanks for your input @GaneshSanap

Comment: You're welcome @fallout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSON formatting, you can only read the column values from same row/list item. You cannot read values from other rows/items.

So, you will not be able to read all items and show them as a drop down using JSON formatting.

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Use view formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting)